# Specify conditions for $\alpha$ so that the iteration $x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha f(x_n)$ converges to root of f.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, convergence-divergence, computer-science

Specify conditions on $\alpha$ so that the iterative process $x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha  f(x_n)$ converges to root of f if started with $x_0$ close to the root.

It is suggested that the proof should supposedly use a Taylor expansion of f centred at its root.

Comment: please give us all informations, is $f$ continuous,or continuous differentiable or $C^\infty$ or analytic.

Comment: I have no idea.. this is how the question was provided in class - no other information.

Comment: For example taking $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl} 0 & x=0 \\ 1 & \text{else} \end{array} \right.$$ converges only if $\alpha = x_0$

Answer (score 1):

The iteration $x = g(x)$ converges to $x_0$ if it starts in an interval containing $x_0$ and over it $\lvert g(x) \rvert < 1$ (this condition isn't necessary, just a convenient check). This [note](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat772/fall10/lecture2.pdf) gives more details.